# Rails form helper to display email fields and their validation errors

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, validation, form

I have a repeated pattern throughout my app that looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group floating-label <%= f.object.errors[:to].any?? "has-error has-feedback" : "" %>">
  <% if f.object.errors[:to].any? %>
    <%= f.label f.object.errors[:to].join(", ") %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.email_field :to, class: "form-control" %>
  <%= f.label :to %>
</div>
```

The only thing that changes is the attribute. Instead of the `:to` attribute, it might be something else. But everything else will remain the same.

I extracted it out into a helper method:

_form.html.erb

```
  <%= field_view "To", f.email_field(:to, class: "form-control") %>
```

form_helper.rb

```
  def field_view(label, *args, &block)
    # label = label.t internalization

    options = args.extract_options!
    field = args.first
    formatter = args.second

    data = capture(&block) if block_given?

    options[:class] = "form-group floating-label #{options[:class]}".strip

    element = formatter ? send(formatter, field) : field

    make_content label, element, options
  end

  def make_content(label, element, options)
    content_tag :div, options do
      element + content_tag(:label, label)
    end
  end
```

I do not want my form_helper to know anything about the field. Because sometimes it will be `f.text_field :to`, `text_field_tag :to`, `f.select`, etc. Too much change happening to make the form_helper aware of it.

What approach would you suggest in order to incorporate that error checking functionality which is shown in the first example?

Answer (score 1):

I would try this (naming needs improvement):

*_helper.rb:

```
  def field_wrapper(errors, &block)
    css_classes = %w(form-group floating-label)
    css_classes << 'has-error has-feedback' if errors.any?
    content_tag :div, class: css_classes, &block
  end

  def error_label(form, errors)
    form.label errors.join(', ') if errors.any?
  end
```

*.html.erb:

```
 <%= field_wrapper f.object.errors[:to] do %>
      <%= error_label f, f.object.errors[:to] %>
      <%= f.email_field :to, class: "form-control" %>
      <%= f.label :to %>
   <% end %>
```